# XDocument Traversal

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm new the the LINQ to XML world. I'm attempting to retrieve the value of `Identity` but only when the `domain` attribute of `Credential` is "NetworkID". Here's the code I'm testing with:

**XML Snippet:**

```
<Sender>
  <Credential domain="NetworkID">
    <Identity>MyIdentity</Identity>
    <SharedSecret>MySharedSecret</SharedSecret>
  </Credential>
  <UserAgent>MyUserAgent</UserAgent>
</Sender>
```

**C#:**

```
var credential = xdoc.Descendants("Sender")
         .Elements("Credential")
         .Where(x => x.Attribute("domain").Value == "NetworkID").FirstOrDefault()
         .Descendants("Identity").FirstOrDefault();
```

**Question:**

Obviously, if the `Credential` node is not found, the LINQ query will generate an error because I'm calling `.Descendants()` on `null`.

Is it possible to write the query so that it return `Identity` or `null` if either element is not found?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove `FirstOrDefault()` after the `Where()`:

```
var credential = xdoc.Descendants("Sender")
                     .Elements("Credential")
                     .Where(x => x.Attribute("domain").Value == "NetworkID")
                     .Descendants("Identity")
                     .FirstOrDefault();
```

`Where()` returns empty result set and `FirstOrDefault()` on empty result set returns null this is why `.Where().FirstOrDefault().Descendants()` caused null reference exception.

Answer (score 1):

If you use

```
    var identity = 
        xdoc.Descendants("Sender")
        .Elements("Credential")
        .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("domain") == "NetworkID")
        .Descendants("Identity")
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

you should get what you want. Or you need to break the code up, doing one FirstOrDefault() in the first part e.g.

```
   var credential = xdoc.Descendants("Sender").Elements("Credential").FirstOrDefault(c => (string)c.Attribute("domain") == "NetworkID");
   var identity = credential != null ? credential.Element("Identity") : null;
```